# How can I build a polynomial lambda function from an list of coefficients?

Tags: python, function, numpy, lambda, mpmath

I have an list of coefficients that correspond to a polynomial expression, ie: `[1,2,0]` corresponds to `x^2 + 2x + 0`. 
I would like to put an arbitrary length array of these coefficients into a lambda function.

Specifically, I am using [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) and I have a list used for the [polyval module](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/calculus/polynomials.html) that is:

```
polyval(ctx, coeffs, x, derivative=False)
```

Given coefficients and a number, `polyval()` evaluates the polynomial.

And I need to use the [findroot module](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/calculus/optimization.html)
that takes a one dimensional function, ie:

```
findroot(lambda x: x**3 + 2*x + 1, 2)
```

How can I construct a lambda function out of a list of coefficients?

Comment: What do you mean "put an arbitrary length array of these coefficients into a lambda function"?

Answer (score 7):

Do you really need a *lambda* function? Using a "normal" function should be easier:

```
def poly(coeffs):
   def calc(x):
      result = 0
      for c in coeffs:
         result = result*x + c
      return result
   return calc

findroot(poly([1,2,0]))
```

And using that `polyval()` function you mention, something like this should work:

```
findroot(lambda x: polyval(ctx, [1,2,0], x))
```

(For an appropriate `ctx` value)

Comment: This is fundamentally right.  Only two tweaks: (1) "ctx" is just self in disguise (polyval is a method), and doesn't need to be passed; and (2) findroot needs an interval or a starting point.  So findroot(lambda x: polyval([1,2,0], x), [-3, -1]) returns mpf('-2.0'), as it should.

Answer (score 1):

sth's `polyval()` based approach looks like the best answer (since you already have access to that function), but if you wanted to implement your own equivalent, the function would look more like:

```
def poly(coeffs):
  def calc(x)
    result = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(reversed(coeffs)):
      result += c*(x**i)
    return result
  return calc

findroot(poly([1,2,0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a lambda expression, the easiset I can think of is using `reduce()`:

```
coeffs = [1, 2, 0]
f = lambda x: reduce(lambda y, a: x*y + a, coeffs, 0.0)
findroot(f, 2)
```

Since this is also tagged `numpy`, you could also use `numpy.poly1d`:

```
coeffs = [1, 2, 0]
f = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)
findroot(f, 2)
```

Comment: Beautiful use of the `reduce` function !

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expression is possible, thanks to the great Python base functions ! The 1st thing is to get couples of (coef, exponent) via the powerful `zip` function:

```
>>> l = [3, 0, 4, -9]
>>> range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1)
[3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> zip(l, range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1))
[(3, 3), (0, 2), (4, 1), (-9, 0)]
```

I use a reversed `range` since greater exponents are at the beginning of the list. Now a polynom is a sum... computed thanks to the `sum` function !

```
>>> f = lambda x: sum([coef*x**exp for (coef, exp) in zip(l, range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1))])
>>> f(3)
84
```

and indeed `3*3^3 + 0*3^2 + 4*3^1 - 9*3^0 = 3*27 + 0 + 4*3 - 9*1 = 81 + 12 - 9 = 84`.
This expression of `f` is correct for all list of coefs `l` whatever its length, thanks to the use of `len(l)`.

Comment: I think the sum variant of ncoghlan's answer is simpler: def f(cfs, x): return sum(c*x**i for i, c in enumerate(reversed(cfs)))